# AppImages will not open Ubuntu 22.04 (Development Branch)

Tags: appimage, 22.04

I just started using the Development branch of Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) and I think it's great!

The only problem is AppImage won't seem to open. I've tried opening it, and it has no prompts or anything, (more specifically, I'm trying to open Ultimaker Cura 4.13.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to make the downloaded program executable.
   Either by right click the app then select "*Permissions*" tab and check "*Allow executing file as program*", or using the command

   ```
   chmod a+x Ultimaker_Cura-4.13.1.AppImage
   ```
2. To run the program, add (dot) and (dash) before the program name

   ```
   ./Ultimaker_Cura-4.13.1.AppImage
   ```
3. The command will shows you the problem, which is (AppImages require FUSE to run).

   To work around that, extract the app using the following code

   ```
   ./Ultimaker_Cura-4.13.1.AppImage --appimage-extract
   ```

That will create a folder with name "squashfs-root" you can run the app using the "AppRun" inside the folder.
Another option is to install the "libfuse2" as mentioned [in the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1402847/349837).

Comment: It started working with the last comment, but very good advice!

Answer (score 15):

You need to install [libfuse2](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/), *The reference implementation of the Linux FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) interface*

```
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

Comment: I did that, but sadly it creates side-effect like opening a pdf from firefox doesn't work.